# Dependency injection net core InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, dependency-injection, automapper

I'm new to AutoMapper and I'm trying to build an API. The default endpoint that comes when starting new API project (WeatherForecast) works fine. However when I'm trying to reach the endpoint api/nationalparks, I get this error:

[image]

Controller:

```
namespace NationalParksAPI.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class NationalParksController : Controller
    {
        private INationalParkRepository _npRepo;
        private ParkyMappings _parksMapper;

        public NationalParksController(INationalParkRepository npRepo, ParkyMappings parksMapper )
        {
            _npRepo = npRepo;
            _parksMapper = parksMapper;
        }

        public IActionResult GetNationalParks()
        {
            var objList = _npRepo.GetNationalParks();
            return Ok(objList);
        }

    }
}
```

Mapper:

```
public class ParkyMappings : Profile
{
    public ParkyMappings()
    {
        CreateMap<NationalParkEntity, NationalParkDTO>().ReverseMap();
    }
}
```

Configure services in start up (Note that AddAutoMapper method is working without using the package AutoMapper, unlike the tutorial I follow):

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContextPool<NationalParksDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("ParksDBConnection")));
        services.AddScoped<INationalParkRepository, NationalParkRepository>();
        services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(ParkyMappings));
        services.AddControllers();
       
    }
```

Entity:

```
public class NationalParkEntity
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string state { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public DateTime Eistablished { get; set; }
}
```

DTO:

```
    public class NationalParkDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string state { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public DateTime Eistablished { get; set; }
}
```

Any inputs will be appreciated.

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Dependency-injection.html#asp-net-core

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't have `ParkyMappings` as a dependency of `Controller`. `ParkyMappings` (as a `Profile` subclass) is only used to initialize `Automapper` at the start of the application. There is no purpose for it to be in the `Controller`.

You should pass `IMapper mapper` to the `Controller` instead:

```cs
namespace NationalParksAPI.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class NationalParksController : Controller
    {
        private INationalParkRepository _npRepo;
        private IMapper _mapper;

        public NationalParksController(INationalParkRepository npRepo, IMapper mapper)
        {
            _npRepo = npRepo;
            _mapper  = mapper;
        }

        public IActionResult GetNationalParks()
        {
            var objList = _npRepo.GetNationalParks();
            var entityList = _mapper.Map<NationalParkEntity[]>(objList)
            return Ok(entityList);
        }

    }
}
```

And, perhaps, use this registration for Automapper instead:

```cs
services.AddAutoMapper(this.GetType().Assembly);
```